# Definition of Equivalence of Categories

Tags: category-theory

I was reading about equivalence of categories. So I came across two definitions and they both do not seem equivalent.

The first definition is the one given on Wikipedia:
Given two categories $C$ and $D$, an equivalence of categories consists of a functor $F$ : $C$ → $D$, a functor $G$ : $D$ → $C$, and two natural isomorphisms $\epsilon: FG→I_D$ and $\eta : I_C→GF$.

The second definition is from the Grothendieck's translated paper [here](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/gk.pdf). The definition is on page four of the paper. In this definitioon he has an extra condition that the composite $F(A) \xrightarrow{F(\phi (A))}FGF(A) \xrightarrow{\psi^{-1}(F(A))} F(A)$ is an identity on $F(A)$.

So my question is are these two definitions equivalent. Thanks.

Comment: You can modify one of the functors, say $G$ into $\hat{G}$, in such a way that $F$ and $\hat{G}$ are still an equivalence in the first sense but are also adjoint to each other. This will automatically produce Grothendieck's extra condition.

Comment: @egreg so are you claiming that both of them are equivalent? Also can you please tell how the extra condition is same as the two functors being adjoints to each other

Comment: Yes, the definitions are equivalent. I worked out the details several years ago; I think that in the book by Stenström it is fully explained.

Comment: These are the same condition on $F$, but not the same condition on the pair $(F, G)$.

Comment: @egreg I am not aware of which book you are talking about can you please also provide the name.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan there was another composition diagram for $G$ as well which I did not mention(not knowing that it was important) would that make these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: @happymath: No. What Grothendieck describes is an adjoint equivalence. This is a stronger condition on the pair $(F, G)$ than the usual notion of equivalence (and there are reasons to argue that it is the correct one). In any case, as egreg says, given an equivalence it is always possible to modify $G$ in such a way as to promote it to an adjoint equivalence. So, again, they are the same condition on $F$, but not the same condition on $(F, G)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks that clarifies a lot